# Puppeteer/CSS Selector for hotel website - Prices return TWICE from Results Page

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

In this hotel website (https://www.marriott.com/default.mi), I am trying to pull hotelNames, prices, and distances from results page and assign them into a results array.

Issue: `prices` **return twice** and messes up my results array from this line of code: `page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] .t-price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()))`

Block of Code:

```
  // Get textContent from results page for: hotel names, prices, distances. Destructuring assignment to assign results of 3 asynchronous fx to 3 separate arrs: `hotelNames`, `prices`, `distances`
  const [hotelNames, prices, distances] = await Promise.all([
    page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map"] span.l-property-name', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim())),
    // ! returns price twice
    page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] .t-price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim())),
    page.$$eval('.js-hotel-distance.l-hotel-distance', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()))
  ]);
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Example of fs.writeFile .txt output file:

```
Courtyard Los Angeles L.A. LIVE, 
The Ritz-Carlton [...]
555,
555,
736,
736, [...]
```

**More detailed explanation of results:**

As you can see from the .txt and screenshot, it takes the price of the first hotel (Courtyard) and duplicates it (555 is shown twice). Then it takes price of second hotel (Ritz-Carlton) and duplicates it (736 is shown twice).

---

**To recreate what I did:**

Go to (https://www.marriott.com/default.mi), enter any Destination, Stay Dates, but after you click `Find Hotels`, ensure to click the checkboxes `Show rates with taxes and all fees` and `Show available hotels only` as this changes the CSS selectors.

---

**Things I've tried:**

i) Without the trim - no difference
`page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] .t-price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent))`

ii) t-price  m-display-block - returns wrong price
`page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] [class="t-price  m-display-block "]', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `[id^="property-record-map-"] .t-price` also returns hidden values, so you need to add one more selector that omits those which will be `.rate-value-container`.

So change

```js
 page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] .t-price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim())),
```

to

```js
page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map-"] .rate-value-container .t-price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim())),
```